Is there any anti-ice system on Cessna Citation II?
I was flying a Cessna Citation II on FlightGear FS. There are some ice on the windshield when it climbs to about 15000 ft. Is there any anti-ice system (or de-ice system) on Cessna Citation II? (I do not mean Citation X or Citation Bravo.) How can I control these things? I looked for them everywhere in the cockpit, and I can't find them.

There are six green switches at the bottom left corner of the board, visible on this FlightGear screenshot:

(Source)
Details of this anti-ice section, from actual aircraft:

(Source)
"W/S" is for windshield. You can send hot air onto the windshield surface with the W/S BLEED switch and anti-ice fluid with W/S ALCOHOL.
Someone asked the same question on Flightgear forum.
